# Need help in defining the models for a game using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I am learning rails and trying to create models based on a small game. I am little confused when designing it. It would be of great help if i some one can help me with it.

I tried look at this

https://github.com/estiens/world_cup_json/tree/master/app/models

But the home_team_id and away_team_id confuses me because i don't have that in my scenarios

My scenario:-

Event
 - Event name
 - Event ID
 - Event winner ID (Team)

Team
 - Team name
 - Team ID
 - Team country

Match
 - Team 1 (I can get ID or name)
 - Team 2 (I can get ID or name)
 - Team 1 rounds
 - Team 2 rounds
 - Match ground
 - Match winner

Upcoming Matches
 - Team 1
 - Team 2
 - Match time

The one thing that confuses me is the relationships. An event can have multiple matches but a match can have only 2 teams.

I tried the following code, but not sure whether am correct

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :match
   belongs_to :team
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :events
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :events
end
```

Please let me know if I am on the right path :)

Edit - 1

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :teams
  belongs_to :team_one, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :team_two, :class_name => "Team"
end
```

If thats the case can I iterate through the matches and find the winners so I can populate in my view. Its kind of analytics by scraping website.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're setting up your relationships properly. As you defined, an event can have multiple matches, so define that:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :matches
end
```

Therefore:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :teams
end
```

Even though a match can only have two teams, it still qualifies as "many" (it's either doesn't have any, has one, or has many). For the sake of clarity, I'm going to include this (maybe it will help illustrate relationships better):

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :players
end
```

And I may as well add this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :team
end
```

I found [the rails guide on AR associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) incredibly valuable while learning about active record relationships. I suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to have something similar to away_team and home_team.
You can't really tell rails that some model "has two" teams, and you will have to tell them apart somehow. So you will need two belongs_to relationships, one for the first team and another one for the second team.

You can name them differently, for example team_one and team_two if concept of "home" and "away" does not make sense in this case.

If one player can challenge another one in your game that might be a good point to start. The player who initiates the game is home team and other one is away team, you will probably need that information at some point later anyway.

Even though it's hard to tell because I don't know anything about your game.

Comment: do you mean some think like this                                                      belongs_to :team_one, :class_name => "Team"
belongs_to :team_two, :class_name => "Team"

Comment: Yeah, that's it. About your other question, you can handle that in few different ways. You could add another belongs_to field and call it :winner, which would point to winning team (it would be nil if there's still no winner). Other option is to have a winner integer field and you would store 1 or 2 in that, depending on which team won. But I like the first solution better, it will be easier to make queries.